# FileReaderSync.ReadAsText() takes long time to read and no callback

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, filereader

I am trying to read an almost big text from a file using `FileReaderSync` , therefore the logic has been implemented as below :

```js
// entry file is validated before

var result = reader.readAsText(entryFile.file());

// at this point result is not filled yet 
// therefore on next line parsing to json is throwing error 

return JSON.parse(result);
```

the problem is that result is not filled for a few seconds, and therefore it throws exception, I tried to look for onload or onloadended events but there these events are not fired (probably not supported ?)

Anyone knows how is it possible to continue the process after the read is completed ?

Comment: So actually it seems it has nothing to with FileReaderSync, nor even with FileReader but simply with the max_length of a String. I tried to `slice()` my big file in smaller chunks, and to concatenate it in the main script, but I still go to this *allocation size overflow* in FF, and now chrome also throws an *Uncaught RangeError: Invalid string length* Nothing to be done I fear, except to keep this as chunks of text, in an Array.

Comment: Is this in Node.js? Why not using `fs.readFileSync()`?

Comment: nope It's just chrome browser.

Comment: What do you try to do with the file? How big is almost big? Why sync and not async/promise? The general approach is to buffer the read meaning you fill a buffer, process it, read next chunk and fill again, repeat until end of file.